# Copy metadata from one 3D tiff file to another

Tags: python, metadata, tiff, exif

Can anyone help me? I'm trying to copy all the metadata from one 3D tiff image to another in python. This is very easy to do with a [perl based program](https://exiftool.org/):

```
exiftool -tagsfromfile <source-file> <target-file>
```

But that is not an easy install to use as a dependency in my python pipeline. There are similar Py libraries that easily to read the metadata tags of a tif image:

```
import exifread

with open("img_w_metadata.tiff", 'rb') as f:
    tags = exifread.process_file(f)
```

or:

```
import piexif

exif_data = piexif.load("img_w_metadata.tiff")
```

But altering that data/inserting new one is very difficult. Exifread has no documentation about it and [piexif seems to only work with jpg files](https://github.com/hMatoba/Piexif/issues/15), giving error if you provide tif:

```
# Open TIFF file for writing     # THIS ERASES THE IMAGE CONTENTS
with open("img_no_metadata", "wb") as f:
    exif_bytes = piexif.dump(exif_data)
    f.write(exif_bytes)
```

Error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last): 
     piexif.insert(exif_bytes, img_new)   File "C:\Users\......\Python39\site-packages\piexif\_insert.py",line 39, in insert
     raise InvalidImageDataError piexif._exceptions.InvalidImageDataError
```

The Pillow library works well with metadata but does not work with 3D images! opencv works well with 3D images but not with metadata, the Tifffile library is also erasing the second image content, hence I'm trying Exif parsers

Cheers,
Ricardo

Comment: I wouldn't describe `exiftool` as a Perl package. It's a program based on Perl that is pretty easily installed anywhere. Where do you want to run it that is causing problems exactly? There's also a Python interface to it. Consider adding `exiftool` to your tags.

Comment: I am creating a python tool that should be easily installed in multiple computers. It is only feasible if the dependencies can be installed automatically with something like pip/conda install. Exiftool seems to require a manual download, copying the lib folder into the C:Windows directory, and then calling the tool from terminal or using its GUI for drag and drop. But my tool needs to be applied to hundreds of image pairs..